# how can we crop an image in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to crop an Image in irregular shape my app, i.e., I select a portion by finger and if I click crop button, the selected portion alone in the Image will be saved in Gallery

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the WriteableBitmapEx library https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ for image cropping.